# Custom UITableViewCell: how to implement layoutSubviews correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have custom UITableViewCell, where I've overrided `layoutSubviews` and have counted coordinates for subviews manually. It works.. but the cell becomes updated only when I use scroll or click on it. Also when I change orientation the cell stays without update.

I've tried to use auto-layout for subviews. And it works fine, and the cell updates as expected: also with orientation change.

But.. I want to use `layoutSubviews`.. as decades of constraints in IB are a sort of headache.. in my case.

So how should I handle `layoutSubviews` to get expected behavior with my custom cell?

I tried using of different updates, those are advised in other questions, but no one of them solved my problem.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSLog(@"------ cell layout subviews ------");

    //self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 0, 300, 80);

    CGRect frame = basketButton.frame;
    int parentX1 = 0;
    int parentY1 = 0;
    int parentX2 = self.contentView.bounds.size.width;
    int parentY2 = self.contentView.bounds.size.height;

    NSLog(@"parentX2: %d", parentX2);
    NSLog(@"contentView: %f", self.contentView.frame.size.width);

    int x, y, h, w;
    int gap = 10;

    w = 80;
    h = 30;
    x = parentX2 - gap - w;
    y = parentY2/2 - h/2;
    frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
    basketButton.frame = frame;

    //NSLog(@"basckeButtonX2: %f", frame.origin.x);

    w = 60;
    h = 15;
    x = frame.origin.x - gap - w;
    y = parentY2/2 - h/2;
    frame = CGRectMake( x, y, w, h );
    priceLabel.frame = frame;

    w = 72;
    h = 72;
    x = gap;
    y = gap;
    frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    imageView.frame = frame;

    x = imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width + gap;
    y = gap;
    w = priceLabel.frame.origin.x - gap - x;
    h = parentY2 - gap*2;
    frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    nameLabel.frame = frame;
}
```

in controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"ProductCell";

    ProductCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];

    NSArray* productsByTableView = [self getProductsByTableView: tableView];
    Product* product = [productsByTableView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = product.name;

    CGRect frame = cell.frame;
    frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
    cell.frame = frame;

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProductCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductCell"];

    CGRect frame = cell.frame;
    frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
    cell.frame = frame;

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    //[cell layoutSubviews];

    return cell.bounds.size.height;
}
```